# Set charset different from UTF-8 in JSON Response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, utf-8, get, ascii

I have this get request in my controller in ASP.NET Core project

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/controller/getlastresult/{id}")]
public IActionResult GetLatestResultForController(string id)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    var list = _dbAccessLayer.GetAllVoteResults();
    var appropriateResults = list.Where(item => item.DeviceId.Equals(id) && item.Status == "Finished")
        .OrderBy(item => item.TimeStarted);

    if (appropriateResults.Any())
        return Ok(Json(appropriateResults.Last().Result));

    return BadRequest();
}
```

It works fine, but in the headers there is Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 as you can see here:

[image]

I need just regular application/json, without charset utf-8, so I guess it will be ASCII charset. Reason being that I use this request with microcontroller which does not like utf-8 encoding.

How do I set charset in the response of my Get request?

Answer (score 0):

For removing charset, you could try middleware like

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.OnStarting((state) =>
    {
        if (context.Response.Headers.Count > 0 && context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Content-Type"))
        {
            var contentType = context.Response.Headers["Content-Type"].ToString();
            if (contentType.StartsWith("application/json"))
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
                context.Response.Headers.Append("Content-Type", "application/json");
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }, null);
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

Comment: This does not work. I tried debugging it, when I trigger the request via postman, this code is not executed, only when I go between pages on my site

Comment: @SaintMSent Share us your cureent `Startup.cs`