# How do I specify request Encoding, response Encoding from the asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

How do I specify request Encoding, response Encoding from the asp.net core?

The asp.net project was specified in Web.config.

```
<globalization requestEncoding="euc-kr" responseEncoding="euc-kr"   />
```

and response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=euc-kr
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 14 Jul 2021 01:50:12 GMT
Content-Length: 229
```

The  response returned from asp.net core project

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 14 Jul 2021 01:53:46 GMT
```

How do I change the globalization encode type ?

Comment: Do you need to do this anymore? Or is it just to try and make responses smaller since you only deal with Korean?

Comment: The job of a web server is to encode the response in a format the client can [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept). Accept-Charset was used to indicate character set support, but is now [obsolete](https://hsivonen.fi/accept-charset/). You should just use UTF-8.

Comment: @Llama I want the server's response to be returned as "charset=euc-kr".

Comment: You already asked this question. The answer remains **why do you want this at all**? Posting an unclear question twice won't get any more answers the second time, only downvotes. `I want the server's response to be returned as` no, you don't. What's the *real* question?

Comment: The answer remains the same. Hard-coding the encoding was a bug in the first place. You don't need `euc-kr`. The default UTF8 works just fine. If you have a real problem, explain what it is. Why do you think you need to hard-code the encoding?

Comment: If you are trying to support a http client that only handles "charset=euc-kr".... Don't. If the client is so old that it doesn't support utf-8, it probably doesn't support the latest `https` standards either. If you have a better reason to use a different encoding, then update your question.

Comment: Existing site code did not specify an encoding type because it was specified in web.config. 
The site being migrated has too much workload to specify encoding types one by one.
My sites require collaboration with other sites, "euc-kr" encoding is required.

Comment: Why did you have to hard-code the encoding in the first place? Did a *custom client* lie about the encoding? All browsers support UTF8 to the point that [Accept-Charset and Accept-Encoding are forbidden headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Charset) and browsers don't send them. JavaScript,  Java, .NET clients have no problem with UTF8, in fact their strings are Unicode to begin with

Comment: @ssong you're repeating the question, not explaining what the actual problem is, assuming there is any problem at all. `My sites require collaboration with other sites` which means they need UTF8, not a non-standard hard-coded encoding. If anything, it sounds like you had a bug in ASP.NET and your site worked by pure chance. `too much workload to specify encoding types one by one` you don't need to. Just remove the unneeded hard-coded, non-standard encoding. `Existing site code did not specify an encoding type` which means UTF8 should be used by default. Which *just works with every language*

Comment: What we're asking is this: what problem does hard-coding the encoding solve? "The old site did it so we do it here" isn't an answer to that question. Why did the old site do it?

Comment: @ssong again and again. Browsers use UTF8. That's not up to discussion. That's why I can write `Καλημέρα` or `안녕하세요` or `صباح الخير` knowing they will appear just fine in your browser. As I already answered to your duplicate question, there are *a lot* of SO questions with Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Cyrillic, Vietnamese, Arabic and Greek text. No hard-coded encodings were used.

Comment: Well, let me change the question.

ASP.NET reuestURL : http://localhost/Home/WebForm?code=%uAC00%uC88C%uB3D9 
ASP.NET CORE reuestURL : http://localhost/Home/WebForm?code=%uAC00%uC88C%uB3D9 
The code below returns the same result.
ASP.NET Code  :  @Request.QueryString["code"]
ASP.NET CORE Code :   @System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Context.Request.Query["code"] , System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("euc-kr")

Can I express it without specifying an encoding type?

Comment: Hi @ssong, I assume you want to achieve the Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core, right? If that is the case, after configuring the application to a multilingual website, in the view page, you could use the IViewLocalizer service to display the localized strings. More detail information, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0)(you could also check the sample).  Besides, you could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362142/), and use middleware to change the response content type.